# How to remove blanks and reorder words

Tags: javascript

I have `.replace(' ', ', ')`

What I want is:

```
Hanks, Tom
```

What I am getting is :

```
Hanks,Tom
```

How do you do this?

Input string is Tom Hanks.

I want Hanks, Tom

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: It works fine.  You're not showing the relevant code.  `console.log(('Hanks Tom').replace(' ', ', '));`

Comment: That should already work

Comment: Why would `replace(' ', ', ')` change the order of the words? I don't see why you would end up with `Hanks,Tom` if your input is `Tom Hanks`.

Answer (score 6):

You can split the string into an array and reorder the bits.

```
var str = "Tom Hanks";
var arr = str.split(' ');

console.log(arr[0] + ', ' + arr[1]);
```